# SSRS - Alternative way for report subscriptions

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

In my project we use MSSQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition where reporting services do not support e-mail subscription and scheduling. In some reasons we cannot upgrade to standard or higher editions.

Are there any alternative way to implement subscription? May be 3rd party libraries.

Task is 
1. Generate report
2. Send report via e-mail
3. Repeat it every Monday.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper application in C# to accomplish this. Essentially the app would render the report out to the file system and then create a mail object for delivery. Code to accomplish this can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e432c8ef-623e-4795-9812-19bf533db9bc/render-a-report-for-attachment-to-email?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Some advice: you should really invest in the proper license rather than relying on workarounds and hacks especially in production servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that creating a SSIS package that uses a report generator task: (http://reportgeneratortask.codeplex.com/) is very easy to implement and use as an alternative for SSRS subscription. I had to do this recently in my current project and it works great.

So basically the SSIS package will cover 2 of 3 tasks:
1. Generate the report (using report generator task)
2. Email the report using "Send Mail Task"

For the last and easy step, create a SQL job that executes the above SSIS package every Monday.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 party tool called as R-Tag. Try to use it if you are still looking solution for your question.